# AWS EC2 deploy w/ Meteor MUP config

Tags: mongodb, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, meteor

Saludos, I'm trying to use Meteor Up to deploy an app I just completed a la Discover Meteor.

MUP is failing on authentication it seems. Here's the error:

```
Meteor-UP : Production Quality Meteor Deployments
--------------------------------------------------


Started TaskList: Setting Up
[XX.XX.127.0] installing node
[XX.XX.127.0] installing node: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
Warning: Permanently added 'XX.XX.127.0' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm new to Meteor and AWS/EC2 and I'm sure I'm making a config mistake but as far as my rookie eyes can see I have everything set up and it seems pretty straightforward.

Here's my mup.json file (w/ omitted sensitive data):

```
{
//server authentication info
"servers": [
  {
    "host": "XX.XX.127.0", //Public IP address
    "username": "xxxx", //AWS username from 'IAM' section
    "password": "xxxx", //corresponding password
    "pem": "/Users/Me/Desktop/fauxappname/xxxKeys.pem"
  }
],

//install MongoDB in the server
"setupMongo": false,

//location of app (local directory)
"app": "/Users/Me/Desktop/fauxappname",

//configure environmental
"env": {
  "ROOT_URL": "http://example.com",
  "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://username:password@server.mongohq.com:10029/fauxappname"
},

"deployCheckWaitTime": 5
```

}

Once that config file is set up then you simply run 'mup setup' in a separate directory with this info within the console. The mup.json file points back to the actual app location.

Any assistance would be welcome. If anyone has any resources that helped them deploy I'd be super interested in that as well. thx

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey)` is an SSH error. Have you verified that you can just ssh into your server with that key?

Comment: I'm using SSHPass - https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979 which is recommended in Discover Meteor if you're using an 'password-based authentication'. I installed in via the homebrew instructions with no errors.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. I was just recommending to check that you can actually ssh into the machine.

Comment: I think @ChristianFritz is correct.  The user that MUP is trying to connect with does not have permission to ssh into the instance.  If you are following the MUP instructions exactly and its still not working, I'd suggest submitting this as an issue here: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues

Also, from this comment, it looks like you shouldn't have to use sshpass if you are using a PEM file:
https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/1#issuecomment-31308419

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your comment carefully enough Christian. I apologize. That's a great recommendation. I tried it and found the proper details to connect to my instance. The tricky part was finding the correct details from AWS. Mine were wrong. I'm going to write something up about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem, but changing this part in mup.json to the following helped install without problems:

```
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "xx.xx.xx.xx", //AWS Public IP Address
      "username": "ubuntu", //default username for AWS instance
      "pem": "/Users/Dropbox/appname/xxx.pem"
    }
  ],
  ........
```

There was no need to give the actual password because I'm guessing the PEM file is doing the SSH job into your instance.